# Force10 S4820T Fiber GBIC is not working

Tags: fiber, layer1, dell

One of our clients bought two of these switches. Now, Dell sent a fiber splitter with a 40GB GBIC. See the pictures below:

[image]

[image]

Now, I connect both GBICs and connect both splitters, one in each switch, and then I use A fiber female adapter to test connectivity.

And nothing happens. I already set the no shutdown command in both switches, but it is not working.

I am not sure if I need to do something else to get these GBICs online.

Comment: How are you cross-connecting the fibers and what's the configuration on the interface?  40G-SR can run as 4x10G or as 40G across 4 Tx and 4 Rx.  If you want to run at the full 40G each Tx needs to be cabled to the corresponding Rx.  2 or 3 out of 4 won't bring the link up.  If you run at 4x10 you can bring the links up individually and make sure they're correct.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I understand you are using a 40G port with a breakout cable (4x10G). In this case, you need to split the 40G port in 4x10G ports.

From the manual:

*Split a single 40G port into four 10G ports.
CONFIGURATION mode
stack-unit stack-unit-number port number portmode quad*

*number: enter the port number of the 40G port to be split.*

Remember that you have to reload the device after change to take effect.